# Difference between "Walker_Nav_menu" and "walker"

Tags: php, menus, walker

Does anyone know what is the difference between extending `Walker_Nav_menu` and `walker`. I learned about Wordpress Nav Walker and found several different tutorials. Do they extends different classes ?

Answer (score 0):

`Walker_Nav_menu` extends `walker` and includes all the markup for a menu. `walker` by itself doesn't have any markup, it just handles walking the tree, and needs to be extended to add markup. See [the documentation:](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker/)

> Extend the Walker class to use it, see examples below. Child classes
>   do not need to implement all of the abstract methods in the class. The
>   child only needs to implement the methods that are needed.

If you're customising the output of a menu, just extend `Walker_Nav_Menu`.